# How to open Dropdown (Bootstrap-UI) above some divs?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

How to open bootstrap-dropdown when i click on cell-div within grid (ng-grid of AngularjJS) ?
I can open it only partially.

`Here's` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXNkgrlC7X5YVQR8g8jG?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to replace `relative` with `absolute` in your `.dropdown` class. To get the wanted effect I added this on the bottom of the head element

```
<style>
    .dropdown {
      position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JxXg8k1NBeMbIhQUygho?p=preview)

Comment: Why not see the lines within drop down ?

Comment: Probably because you have error in ng-controller. When I set lines with Chrome, I can normally see them

Comment: I'm not Angular guy, but you are passing cellTemplate as a string. It seems to me that this part isn't compiled. I hope that this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile will help you

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `overflow` is `hidden` within this element. Add the following CSS to enable visibility.

```
.ui-grid-cell {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This will need to be added BELOW all other style within your CSS to ensure it is not overwritten by another rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://github.com/vergerf/angular-scroll-dropdown.

It's very useful in a `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` environment.